# IIS 7.0 using netTcpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, tcp

I've been trying for more than a week without any success at all, to host  wcf service using netTcpBinding.

With http, everything is ok. But with tcp problems arise.

I have performed all the steps I'm supposed to, in order to host my service in WAS:

.Net 3.0 Features are enabled, including http and non-http Activation

. At IIS Manager/ Manage Web Site / Advanced Settings, both, http and net.tcp protocols are enabled.
-I also add net tcp to site binding

When i run the webservice, i have this exception : Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Here's what my Web.Config looks like:

```
   <services>
        <service name="Services.Library.OrderService"  BehaviorConfiguration="OrderServiceBehavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint  address="WSOrder.svc" 
                        binding="netTcpBinding"
                        bindingConfiguration="netTcpStreaming"
                        name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint"
                        contract="Services.Interface.IOrderService" >


                <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>

            </endpoint>

            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/" />                  
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>


        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="OrderServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTcpStreaming"
                     openTimeout="10:00:00"
                     closeTimeout="10:00:00" 
                     receiveTimeout="10:00:00"
                     sendTimeout="10:00:00"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >

                <!-- this is for demo only. Https/Transport security is recommended -->
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
         </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
```

Can you tell me please what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 for poor title and hard to follow question. I'll remove downvote if you fix the title (make it searchable, lose the MiXeD CaSe NoISe WordZ) and if you clean up the formatting so its easier to see what you're asking, what results you're getting, what results you WANT to get, and what you've already done.

Comment: For future reference, using phrases like "HELP PLEASE" or "URGENT" makes people immediately dismiss your question (because it sounds immature and greedy). Believe it or not, omitting such phrases might yield you quicker and better answers.

Comment: @Ofir - no this is most certainly a better fit here. I end up doing this sort of WCF/IIS configuration as part of my dev role all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having similar issues myself recently, but eventually managed to get things working.

You say "At IIS Manager/ Manage Web Site / Advanced Settings, both, http and net.tcp protocols are enabled. -I also add net tcp to site binding". 
This setting also needs to be manually set at the sub "virtual root" level if there is one. Is this running under a virtual root in IIS? If so, check this setting there.

Have you also set the bindings at the *web site* level "edit bindings"? You'll need to add a net.tcp binding here. In your case:

```
Type: net.tcp
Binding Information: 808:*
```

If both of those fail, post back. I'll keep an eye out :)

**[Edit in response to your comments]**

OK - I've had a closer look at your config and it doesn't look right to me. This is the server side config? [ie not for a calling client]

I've recreated a config, based on yours, for you to experiment with. [I've stripped out the mex stuff - just a barebones tcp binding]

Have you been using the WCF Service Configuration Editor to generate this config, or have you been doing it by hand? If by hand, don't - use the config editor. It saves lives!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpStreaming" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.Library.OrderService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="netTcpStreaming" contract="Services.Interface.IOrderService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer;

1. it is not over a  virtual directory 

2. I already add a net.tcp binding like bellow : 

Type: net.tcp
Binding Information: 808:*

:(

Comment: im sorry but i dont see any difference between this config and my config, what did u change exactly? i notice that there is no base address nor mex endpoint in your config, which are recomended. 

infact, this is server config, generetad by config editor first, but i added information concerning my wcf by hand, like nettcpbinding, endpoint, baseadress etc...

Comment: @user275384: you need to shift to "Something is wrong and I don't know what. Maybe I should try listening to the people that are helping me." mode.  You should try either one of these bindings and see if it works for you. THEN start adding. simple. I am probably done with this question. See you next time.

Comment: I didn't change anything directly, I just transcribed your settings into a clean config file using the config editor, cutting it down to the bare minimum. I did miss out the baseAddresses, which I've added back in. Do you still get the same error when you try this config?

Answer (score 1):

If you want mex, you have to have an http endpoint defined whether you use it or not.

drop the mex and your service should work just fine.

here is a working net.tcp binding from one of my integration tests.... compare it to what you have..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service">
        <endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfServiceShared.IService" name="TcpBinding" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/ServiceHost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @user275384: did you also drop the serviceMetadata element? and you might want to better format the xml. that is proper SO manners.

Comment: did u mean this one :   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
i drop it also, but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is totally a guess but you may want to try futzing with this code:

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/" />                  
</baseAddresses>
```

Maybe change `net.tcp` to `http`